# How to delete multiples registers in jqgrid using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

Could you please help me how I could do to delete multiple records selected in my jqgrid? I've tried a number of ways, but so far not got any success. I will be grateful to anyone who can help me.

```
jQuery("#grid-table").jqGrid({
        //direction: "rtl",
        url: "/Lojas/GetLojas",
        datatype: 'json',

        mtype: 'Get',
        height: '100%',
        colNames: [ ' ',
                    'Name',
                    'Description'
                  ],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'myac', index: '', width: 65, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    delOptions: { recreateForm: true, url: '/Lojas/Delete', beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback },
                    editformbutton: true, editOptions: { recreateForm: true, url: '/Lojas/Edit', closeAfterEdit: true, beforeShowForm: beforeEditCallback, closeOnEscape: true }
                }
            },
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: "int", editable: false },
            { key: false, name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true},
            { key: false, name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: true}
        ],

        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        pager: pager_selector,
        altRows: true,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiboxonly: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiboxonly: true,
        caption: "Lojas Cadastradas"
    });

      //navButtons
    jQuery("#grid-table").jqGrid('navGrid', pager_selector,
        {   
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            search: true,
            refresh: true,
            view: true,
        },
        {
            url: '/Lojas/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true
        },
        {
            url: '/Lojas/Create',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            recreateForm: true
        },
        {
            url: '/Lojas/Delete',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true
        },
        {
            //search form
            recreateForm: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterSearch: true,
            multipleSearch: true
        },
        {
            //view record form
            recreateForm: true
        }
    )
```

Code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Loja loja)
    {
        Loja lojaToDelete = db.Lojas.Find(loja.Id);
        if (lojaToDelete == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        db.Lojas.Remove(lojaToDelete);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(loja);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to change prototype of Delete function `public ActionResult Delete(Loja loja)` to

```cs
public void Delete(string id)
```

The main problem in your code is the following. Corresponds to [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2) jqGrid post `id` parameter to `url: '/Lojas/Delete'`. You can rename the name of `id` parameter using `prmNames`. In the case you can use `prmNames: {id: "Id"}`, but it's not really required.

If multiple rows needed be deleted then `id` string will be comma separated and you can use something like

```
public void Delete(string id)
{
    var ids = id.Split(',');
    foreach (lojaId in ids) {
        Loja lojaToDelete = db.Lojas.Find(lojaId);
        if (lojaToDelete == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        db.Lojas.Remove(lojaToDelete);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, Oleg! I just changed your code to convert the string to integer to find the record in database and this code worked perfectly! Thank you!!!

Final code:

`public void Delete(string id)
{
 var ids = id.Split(',');
 foreach (var lojaId in ids) {
  int idLoja = Convert.ToInt32(lojaId);
  Loja lojaToDelete = db.Lojas.Find(idLoja);
  if (lojaToDelete == null)
   throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  db.Lojas.Remove(lojaToDelete);
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
}`

Comment: @David: You are welcome! I just wrote the code without testing it. I recommend you to verify whether the thrown exception is correct in your environment or you should use another one. You can use `errorTextFormat` callback to customize the text displayed on the client side of delete error. One can customize on the server side the serialization of exceptions (see `HandleJsonExceptionAttribute` in [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935)).